# Universal Image Loader not working on BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-imageview, baseadapter, universal-image-loader

Hi I am using the Universal Image Loader for Android library to download images Asynchronously to my `Android` app.

It works fine when It is used on a `Activity` but I can't make it work on a `Adapter`

It shows the default image but it does not display the image from myUrl.

Here you have my code:

```
public class AdapatadorImagenesDetalle extends BaseAdapter {

private Context contexto;
private int position;
ImageView imageView;

public AdapatadorImagenesDetalle(Context c,int pos) {
    contexto = c;
    position = pos;
}

public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int positionView, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 imageView = new ImageView(contexto);
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(myUrl, imageView, new ImageLoadingListener() {
  @Override
  public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) 
  {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
  }
  @Override
  public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) 
  {
     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
  }
  @Override
  public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
  }
  });

 return imageView;

}
}
```

Any clue why is this happening ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I am trying to show those images on a eco-gallery

Comment: What is `myUrl`? you are not doing anything on `onLoadingCompleted` if `myUrl` is loaded successfully.

Comment: Set layout params to your ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
    ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
}
```

Also check this:

```
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
}
```

It looks like you didn't implement this method. May be you need that:

```
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    ((ImageView)view.setImageBitmap(loadedImage))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a static method in a class named "TratarImagenes" Spanish for "ProcessImages", then override the UIL methods. This method also calculate the time in milliseconds of the downloading process, so you can use it for testing proposes.

```
 public class TrataImagenes {

    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;


    /**
     * Este método carga una imagen desde una URL o url local, y si falla, muestra la imagen
     * pasada como ID resource imgenFalloDireccionRDrawable.
     *
     * @param urlDeLaImagen                url de la imagen a cargar
     * @param imageView                    ImageView donde se carga la imagen
     * @param imgenFalloDireccionRDrawable dirección del drawable a cargar si falla
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean cargarImagenConUIL(
            String urlDeLaImagen, final ImageView imageView, final int imgenFalloDireccionRDrawable) {
        final boolean[] funciona = {false};
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        final long[] antesTiempo = {0};
        imageLoader.displayImage(
                urlDeLaImagen, imageView, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        antesTiempo[0] = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(
                            String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                        funciona[0] = false;
                        Log.e("Universal Image Loading:", "falló la carga");
                        ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(imgenFalloDireccionRDrawable);
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        funciona[0] = true;
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.i("Universal Image Loading", "OK" + "en" + " "+ String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()-antesTiempo[0]));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                        funciona[0] = false;
                        Log.e("Universal Image LOading:", "descarga cancelada");
                    }
                });
        return funciona[0];
    }
}
```

Also remember to implement the options and configuration of your UIL. I do it in the ApplicationClass, the above options and config are an example, you can use default or customs options&configuration according to your needs.

```
    public void cargarConfiguracionDeUniversalImageLoader() {
    //UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER OPCIONES
    DisplayImageOptions optionesBasicas = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            //Roberto- Haciendo pruebas con el monitor de memoria.
            //desabilitar el caché de memoria ahorra hasta 10 MB en ejecución.
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .considerExifParams(true)
                    // Bitmaps in RGB_565 consume 2 times less memory than in ARGB_8888.
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(500)).build();
    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER CONFIGURACION----------
    ImageLoaderConfiguration configuracionBasica =
            new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).threadPoolSize(2).defaultDisplayImageOptions(optionesBasicas)

                    .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 320, null).
                    diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024).diskCacheFileCount(100).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(configuracionBasica);
}
```

I hope this post helps you.